# Browser directly calling back-end URL instead of UI app URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am 3 weeks old to Angular so a little confused about how it works.
Setup: We have 1 container running 2 applications (UI and Backend) UI runs on 8080 and backend runs on 8181.

Issue: When we submit the credentials on the login page, browser is making a direct call to the back-end to check if the user exists. I traced this down by looking at the network calls in Browser's developer tools. Not sure how the framework is working but how does the browser directly call the back-end instead of the UI app. As the application will mature, back-end port won't be even open for outside communication.

Details - I am implementing a login page - It basically calls the UI app to render the login.html and once the user submits the page with user ID & password; it goes to the controller which goes makes an API call to check if the user exists in DB

Browser(ClientUIIP:8080) --> UI --> Backend(check if user exists)

I have a controller.js with below code

```
var serverPath = 'http://localhost:8181/backend'
//Backend API URL's
var users = '/users';
<code>
function LoginCtrl($scope, $state, $http, $rootScope){
    this.cancel = $scope.$dismiss;
    $scope.showLogin = true;
    $scope.message = "";

    this.submit = function(username, email){
        $http.get(serverPath + users + "/" + username)
        .success(function(response){
            if(response.name === username){
                $scope.currentUser = username;
                window.localStorage.setItem('CurrentUser', JSON.stringify(username));
                $scope.showLogin = false;
                return $state.go('index.main')
            }else{
                $scope.message = "Login not valid, please try again";
            }
        });
    };

    this.logout = function () {
        window.localStorage.setItem('CurrentUser', null);
        $scope.currentUser = null;
        return $state.go('index.login')
    };

    if(getCurrentUser() != null){
        $scope.showLogin = false;
    }
};
```

Please let me know if anybody has an idea what needs to be changed so the browser calls the UI and then UI can make the call to back-end if the user exists or not.

Thank you

Comment: Hmm. Your app is calling the backend server because you explicitly told it to when you provided the `$http.get` method with the backend URL (`localhost:8181/backend`)

Comment: @Pop-A-Stash Sorry but that backendURL is for the UI app to communicate with the backendAPP. For some reason its picking that up and calling that directly from the browser instead of flowing through the UI App

Comment: What you said makes no sense. If you load the above code in a browser, it will call `localhost:8181` directly. The ONLY way to change that is to change the URL. If you want your `$http` call to call "UI App", you must make the URL `localhost:8080`

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you showed us the details of the request/response as seen in the developer tools of the browser. And, tell us how the request/response differs from your expectations